# CSS selector based on element text?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select an element in css based on element text?

ie:

```
li[text=*foo]

<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
```

That probably doesn't work.

Edit: Also only need to support Chrome.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Not with CSS directly, you could set CSS properties via JavaScript based on the internal contents but in the end you would still need to be operating in the definitions of CSS.

Comment: Try :empty css selector. Worked out for me.

Comment: @DmitriiMalyshev Link to the description of the `:empty` selector: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp

Answer (score 141):

I know it's not exactly what you are looking for, but maybe it'll help you.

You can try use a jQuery selector [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), add a class and then do a normal style for a class.

Comment: This worked for me.  Ended up using something like: `$("div:contains('Text')")
     .closest("div.parent_div")
     .css("background", "#555");`

Comment: @dineshygv No it should not be marked as the answer. The question asked for a CSS Selector. This answer is a jQuery selector which is entirely different and adds the dependency of using jQuery. Proper CSS Selectors do not require any special library, only conformance to CSS & DOM standards by the browser.

Comment: Unbelievably, this works in Rails unit tests `assert_select '.text-muted:contains("Total Raised")', 'Total Raised'`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/testing.html#testing-views I did not expect it to because I thought the unit tests use Ruby CSS selectors, not JQuery.

Answer (score 14):

It was probably discussed, but as of CSS3 there is nothing like what you need (see also "[Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/css-3-content-selector)").
You will have to use additional markup, like this:

```
<li><span class="foo">some text</span></li>
<li>some other text</li>
```

Then refer to it the usual way:

```
li > span.foo {...}
```

Comment: This can be confusing. The selector being described is going off of the class on the element, not the text inside of it. Yes, it says "You will have to use additional markup", but with a cursory glance, that could easily be missed.