# Selenium-Webdriver: Get attributes after finding an element

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm still rather new with the automation stuff, so this might sound like a stupid question.
I did google search the hell out of it, before posting a question though :)

Anyways, here is the problem

I am automating tests on an Android device
One of the tests is to verify that an item has been marked as 'Favorite'
Code snippet of page is:

```
<li class = "resultItem isFavorite" data-index="2">
<div class="name" data-cis="4ced6feb-3b5c-415a-ae1c-0b8bca8e3c85" onclick="return true">f,f</div>
</li>
```

I can find the element in the list with `el = @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[class='name' and text() ='f,f']")`. I was hoping that el.class would show me resultItem isFavorite.
Instead what i get is: Selenium:WebDriver::Element

If an item is not marked as favorite, the isFavorite flag isn't added in the  field.
I was hoping to use isFavorite to verify that an item is marked as favorite, but I can't seem to get it into a variable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you really want here is something like the following:

```
# Note: Possibly incorrect Ruby code here. 
# Written from memory.
el = @driver.find_element(:xpath, "/your/xpath/here")
# Could also your el["class"]
element_class_attribute = el.attribute("class")
```

Ordinarily, using most attribute names like `src` (as in `el.src`) would give you a runtime error. However, it happens that `class` has a special meaning in Ruby, and every object has a `class` attribute, which is the Ruby class.

Comment: Hi Jim, I tried get_attribute and variations of it.  But it kept coming up with 'undefined method'. I'll keep looking to see what the ruby get_attribute equivalent is.  I did find another way around this problem though.

Comment: The actual ruby method you want is .attribute(). I've corrected the sample code in my answer to reflect this. Remember, you can always find the API documentation for Ruby at [this link](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/index.html)

Comment: @SSchneid So it's a comment, which means I can't go back and edit it. Moreover, it's a comment that's over 4 **years** old. The project has long since moved to GitHub from Google Code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm reading two questions here.  First, the short, easy one.

***Q: Now that I've found `el`, how do I access its class HTML attribute?***

A: Use `el.attribute('class')`, or its short-hand `el['class']`.  See [Selenium::WebDriver::Element.attribute](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#attribute-instance_method).

Now the longer one.

***Q: How can I test that the item denoted by `el` is marked as a favorite?***

A: See below.

To give a better answer, I would need more information about the composition of the page we're testing.  I've made some basic assumptions:

- The page has one or more `li` elements with class `'resultItem'`, some of which also have class `'isFavorite'`.
- Each of these `li` elements have one or more child elements, one of which is guaranteed to be a `div` with class `'name'`.
- Only one such child `div` will have text `'f,f'`.

Broadly speaking, we have two ways to go about this.

1. We can find the relevant `div`, then verify that its parent `li` has class `'isFavorite'`.
2. We can find all `li` elements with class `'isFavorite'`, then verify that one of them contains the relevant `div`.

There are a lot of things we need to be aware of here.

For Selenium, XPath selectors are good at finding by text, but [poor at finding by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808921/selecting-a-css-class-with-xpath).  CSS selectors are good at finding by class, but [cannot find by text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text).  Neither of these is ideal for finding the `div` we are after.

As mentioned above, we can get the class (attribute) of an element using `element['class']`.  As we found out, `element.class` calls `Object#class`, giving us `Selenium::WebDriver::Element`.  `el['class']`, in this case, gives us the String `'name'`.  If called on its parent element, we would get `'resultItem isFavorite'`.

We can get at an element's text using `element.text`.  `el.text` would give us `'f,f'` in this case.  Like [JavaScript's textContent function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), it returns the text of the element and all of its descendents, so calling `text()` on the parent element would also give us `'f,f'`.  Note that this method can be slow, and will return an empty String if the element is not visible in some way.  Use with caution.  See [Selenium::WebDriver::Element.text](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#text-instance_method) for more info.

Given the above, lets see how Methods #1 and #2 play out.  (The following is Ruby 1.9.3.)

Method #1

```
div_elements = @driver.find_elements(:css, 'li > div.name').select { |e| e.text == 'f,f' }
div_element = div_elements.first

parent_li = div_element.find_element(:xpath, './..')
parent_li_classes = parent_li['class'].scan(/\S+/)
if parent_li_classes.include?('isFavorite')
  # PASS
else
  # FAIL
end
```

Method #2

```
favorite_items = @driver.find_elements(:css, 'li.isFavorite')
if favorite_items.any? { |item| item.find_element(:css, 'div.name').text == 'f,f' }
  # PASS
else
  # FAIL
end
```

Method #2, Refactored

```
if @driver.find_elements(:css, 'li.isFavorite').any? { |item| item.text == 'f,f' }
  # PASS
else
  # FAIL
end
```

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby**

```
element.attribute("attribute name")
```

**Python**

```
element.get_attribute("attribute name")
```

**Java**

```
element.getAttribute("attribute name")
```

**C#**

```
element.GetAttribute("attribute name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by going at it another way:

```
element = @driver.find_elements(:class, "isFavorite")
element.each do |t|
   if t.text() == 'f,f' then
       result = "pass"
   end
end
```

I have a feeling this might be really slow, if there is a long list...but at least it works :)

Thanks

Jeff