# How to write a CSS locator for a button

Tags: css, selenium

```
<div class="test" data-credit-card-index="1">

    <button class="test1 test">Delete</button>
    <button class="test1 test">Edit</button>
```

I want to write a CSS locator for the Edit button.. it's under the [data-credit-card-index="1"] section... there will be a few more credit-card there.. so I have to use the [data-credit-card-index="1"]  plus Edit to locate my locator.

Anyone can help here? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

For Selenium:

```
By.cssSelector('.test[data-credit-card-index="1"] button.test:eq(1)')
```

Or with XPath:

```
By.xpath('div[@data-credit-card-index="1"]/button[contains(text(),"Edit")]')
```

**Original answer (jQuery)**

First:

```
$('.test[data-credit-card-index="1"] button:contains("Edit")');
```

Second:

```
$('.test[data-credit-card-index="1"] button.test:eq(1)');
```

But this is better to use an additional class instead, if you are allowed:

```
<div class="test" data-credit-card-index="1">

    <button class="test1 test delete-button">Delete</button>
    <button class="test1 test edit-button">Edit</button>
```

and:

```
$('.test[data-credit-card-index="1"] .edit-button');
```

Comment: Not going to downvote this because you did give an answer to is correct given the context (Selenium) but your first answer isn't (`contains` is not part of CSS selector standard.)

Comment: Sorry, I have missed the context because of cforcloud's jQuery based answer.

Answer (score -1):

For jquery, you could use [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), like

```
$("button:contains('Edit')")
// or
$('[data-credit-card-index="1"]').find("button:contains('Edit')")
```

Comment: I'm writing selenium automation, ('[data-credit-card-index="1"]').find("button:contains('Edit')") looks like not work for me

Comment: Looks like selenium has problems with :contains http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595149/alternative-of-contains-in-cssselector-selenium-webdriver. Try :eq(1) as suggested above. But actually it should work by the **[selenium docs](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors)**

Comment: `contains` is not going to work with Selenium since `contains` is not part of the CSS selector standard. It's just that jQuery (rather, it's backing selector engine, Sizzle) implements their own version of it. So this answer is correct for a jQuery selector (which *isn't* a CSS selector) but is incorrect in the context of Selenium.