# Get HTML element by text

Tags: java, selenium

Consider i have this `HTML`:

```
<span class="bla">Create New</span>
```

How can i get this element ?

I try:

```
span:contains("Create")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "by xpath" locator:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[. = 'Create New']"));
```

Comment: Can i also have it with css ?

Comment: @davidhol from what I know, no, you have to use by xpath: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595149/alternative-of-contains-in-cssselector-selenium-webdriver.

Comment: What does the dot doing ?

Comment: @davidhol the "dot' refers to the span element's text.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - xpath selector to get by text:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Create New')]"));
```

Comment: The question is "Get HTML element by text".

Comment: This class named bla appears several times.

Comment: Updated to get by text.