# CSS "inner-html" technique?

Tags: html, css, innerhtml

I was wondering if there was a way to query elements according to the word it contains. So, if I have:

```
<div id="globalPageHeader">
    <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
```

I want any `#globalPageHeader h1` that has the word `Home` in it, to have a `display` property of `none`.

Obviously this example wouldn't work, but I was wondering if there's something like it:

```
#globalPageHeader h1(innerHTML == "Home") {
     display: none;
}
```

I don't want to use JavaScript's `innerHTML` because I have no access to the javascript parts of the admin.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: There used to be a contains() pseudo class - but it was removed for who knows why - however, jQuery still supports it in their sizzle selector

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With pure CSS, that’s impossible.

Comment: Ahh. Okay, I was afraid of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible using CSS. You can, however, do it using jQuery. Why not just add a class to the desired h1 tags?

Comment: Yeah, I would do that, except since it's global, it's a lot of work. Plus, no jQuery because I don't have access to the JavaScript side of the admin. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. What you can do is to add an attribute to the `<h1>` element.
For example `title` :

```
<div id="globalPageHeader">
    <h1 title='Home'>Home</h1>
</div>
```

And then in the CSS:

```
#globalPageHeader h1[title = 'Home'] {
     display: none;
}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Why not just add a class?