# Is it possible for a pseudo element to inherit the text of the parent element?

Tags: css

I need to duplicate the text for some divs and style it differently. I'm going to use pseudo elements for this.

In regards to the `content` property, I know I can grab attributes from the parent element like I did in the demo code below, but is there a way to grab the actual text of the parent? I didn't find anything in the docs or online saying it could or couldn't be done.

```css
div::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div data-text="This is the data-text contetnt">This is the div content</div>
```

I'll add that if this were to be done in JS it would use the `textContent` property not the `innerHTML` property

Comment: Just a reminder - you can't have HTML inside your pseudo element. So if you have a `span` or `em` or any other HTML tags there they would be displayed as is.

Comment: Its not possible to get the `innerHTML` of the parent, but its possible to get the data-attribute of the parent using the [`attr()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr), as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71187373/6908282)

Answer (score 1):

I think youre basically asking if you can get the equivalent of the DOM innerHTML property.

The answer is it cant be done in CSS ([CSS "inner-html" technique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628083/css-inner-html-technique))

So you would have to use JS

Comment: Yea kind of. But I don't need any html if there is any. I just need the text of the parent. Nothing associated with the children of the div.

Comment: I'll add - Basically like the Node.textContent property in JS