# Passing innerText of html element into :before css class

Tags: html, css

So I have an h1 tag in my html, with text in it.

```
<h1>123</h1>



h1:before{
    content:"?????";
    }
```

Now I want this text to be used in my css before pseudo class, and the text is dynamic, it will be changed during the runtime of the app, so it's not static.
I need the before content always reflect the current inner text.

Help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible for a pseudo element to inherit the text of the parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682521/is-it-possible-for-a-pseudo-element-to-inherit-the-text-of-the-parent-element)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ***attr*** (attribute) fot that. I searched on web, and found this article: [css-before-and-after](https://betterprogramming.pub/mastering-css-before-and-after-ecf1d59d9a3d)

CSS:

```
h1::before {
  content: attr(data-dynamic);
  margin-right: 10px;
  
}
```

HTML :

```
<h1 data-dynamic='something' > Magic </h1>
```

Result:

Something Magic

---

So, you pass in ***data-dynamic***(or another name) what you want in the before or after content.

Comment: I don't have this attribute on the h1 tag. I need access to the inner text and not any other attributes

Comment: Read about that: [element.before()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/before), but use JavaScript or JQUERY. I can show you, case it is not clear yet.

Comment: OK. Nice to learn new stuff. I thought there is a css way to do this