# C# selenium webdriver css selector for label with only text Sign Out

Tags: c#, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

I was not able to get satisfactory answer after searching on google.
So could you please guide me on this?
I have a div containing li,a,labels below it.
I am able to find the div using CssSelector by its class name.
Now inside this div I want to get a label with its text and then click on it.
The label is as belo:

<label>Sign Out</label>

How to do that ?

I have a working solution using XPath and iterating over all labels inside div, but I am unable to get it using CssSelector.

My Solution:

```
IWebElement menu = CurrentDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='menu-panel right']"));
IWebElement logoutLabel = menu.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[text()='Sign Out']"));
```

or
by using foreach:

```
var coll = menu.FindElements(By.TagName("label"));
foreach (var label in coll)
{
  if(label.Text.Trim() =="Sign Out")
  {
      Log("Sign out was found.");
      label.Click();
      break;
  }
}
```

I tried with CssSelector:

```
IWebElement logoutLabel = menu.FindElement(By.CssSelector(":contains('Sign Out')"));
IWebElement logoutLabel = menu.FindElement(By.CssSelector("label:contains('Sign Out')"));
IWebElement logoutLabel = menu.FindElement(By.CssSelector("label['Sign Out']"));
```

But these are not working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a very good reason why your CSS selector wouldn't work, specifically the `contains` bit is where it falls over. Why?

It isn't part of the CSS selector specification, and therefore would never work.

The `contains` that we all know and love is actually coming from **Sizzle**, the CSS selector engine behind [jQuery.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

If you want text-based searching, you will either **have** to use XPath, or get a **collection** of those elements (using any locator you see fit) and then filter them down in code (like you have done in your `foreach` loop). There isn't a native CSS-style way to do "text based searching".

In terms of your current code, you will probably also fall over because XPath requires a little "poking" to tell it to search only the child elements of your current "element".

```
IWebElement menu = CurrentDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='menu-panel right']"));
IWebElement logoutLabel = menu.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[text()='Sign Out']"));
```

Should be:

```
IWebElement menu = CurrentDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='menu-panel right']"));
IWebElement logoutLabel = menu.FindElement(By.XPath(".//label[text()='Sign Out']"));
```

(Note the "." in the XPath)

Also, your `foreach` loop should have worked, therefore you will have to put a breakpoint in there and check exactly what is being returned by `menu.FindElements(By.TagName("label"));`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a very good answer and you explained in detail. By adding break point analyzing further I was able to understand in detail. I think my method of iterating using foreach is more suitable for my needs. Thanks Arran!  regards, rahoolm

Comment: This opened up my eyes on finding things for my company.  I knew the jQuery worked for the IDE, but when writing the C# code I was getting issues.  Being able to located via XPath allows me to select the things I can physically see with names on them.  Now if it moves on the page, the script won't break!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `:contains()`, which is a jQuery selector, not a CSS selector.
Apparently there is no way to achieve such thing using only CSS.

More info [CSS selector based on element text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text)