# Access span text from css

Tags: css, html

Following is the Jsfiddle I tried

http://jsfiddle.net/LpH8B/2/

```
<span>*</span>
<br>
<span>*</span>
    <br>
<span>hdhdf</span>

span[text='*']
{
    color:red;
}
```

what i want is the two spans with * content in it to be accessed from css?

Comment: If that span is dynamically added, and the value of span is consistent, well just my opinion, would it be good if a class would be just added for that? like .askterisk {}. I know you already thought of it, but just giving an opinion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector based on element text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is possible without using data attributes instead: http://jsfiddle.net/TkKwp/

**HTML:**

```
<span data-text="*"></span>
```

**CSS:**

```
span[data-text="*"]:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  color: red;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the extra class, this might be helpful:

**EDITED**

**HTML**

```
<span>*</span>
<br>
<span>*</span>
<br>
<span>hdhdf</span>
```

**CSS**

```
span:nth-child(1),
span:nth-child(2){
    color:red;
}
```

EDITED.

Answer (score 1):

just Using CSS results cannot be achieved unless you use some attribute in `span` tag.

However using a bit jquery **[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** you can get the result.

check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/LpH8B/4/)**.

```
$('span')
.filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == '*'; })
.css('color','#ef8913');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get from the text value directly, you can use JQuery or Javascript to do such a job based on the internal contents but still you need to be operating in the definitions of CSS.