# Selenium: finding element using css equivalent xpath //span[text()="TEXT"]

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-ide

I have the below html element

```
<span class="iconLinkContext icon_document_add_24x24">Copy Item from...</span>
```

I am finding the above element using xpath

```
//span[text()="TEXT"]
```

What is the equivalent in css?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector based on element text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text)

Comment: Thank you for the link, helpful