# Using CSS to Show Image after Specific Text Value

Tags: css

Is there a way to have an image appear after an H3 element but only for the H3 element that contains a specific word of text?

Comment: short answer, no. You will need javascript for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text