# Selenium CSS selector syntax for checking class and text both

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath

Question is for JAVA + Selenium:

My HTML is:

```
<section class="d-menu d-outclass-bootstrap unclickable d-apps d-app-list">
<section class="standard-component image-sequence-button" tabindex="0" role="link">
    <div class="image-region">
        <div class="core-component image">...
    </div>
    <div class="sequence-region">
        <div class="core-component section">
            <div>
                <section class="standard-component text hide-section-separator-line">
                    <div class="text-region">
                        <div class="core-component text">
                            <span class="main-text">BART Times</span>
                            <span class="sub-text">Provider</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section class="standard-component speech-bubble hide-section-separator-line">...
                <section class="standard-component text">...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-region">
        <div class="core-component button" tabindex="0" role="link">...
    </div>
</section>
<section class="standard-component image-sequence-button" tabindex="0" role="link">...
<section class="standard-component image-sequence-button" tabindex="0" role="link">...
<section class="standard-component image-sequence-button" tabindex="0" role="link">...</section>
```

**EDIT:**

All `<section class="standard-component image-sequence-button"...` have exact same structure and hierarchy (same attributes for all tags). The only thing that changes are the TEXT values of the tags(e.g. `span`)

**PART1:**
I'm looking for various elements inside the second `section` tag. So, What I'm trying to do is get the `<span class="main-text">` which has a value `BART Times` because of the business requirement.

I already know how to get it via xpath:

My xpath (verified via firebug):

```
"//section//div[@class = 'sequence-region']//section[@class = 'standard-component text hide-section-separator-line']//span[@class = 'main-text' and text() = '%s']"
```

I can get the `span` tag via checking for %s values (e.g. BART Times).

However, due to design considerations, we've been told to use CSS only. So, I tried to come up with a CSS counterpart for the above xpath but did not find it.

The following CSS

```
"section div.sequence-region section.standard-component.text.hide-section-separator-line span[class=main-text]"
```

returns all the `span` tags under all the `section` tags.

**Question1:** How do I get the `span` tag which has a certain TEXT value (the %s part of xpath)?

Things I've tried for that last `span` tag which did not worked(according to the firebug):

- span.main-text[text='BART Times']

  span[class=main-text][text='BART Times']

  span.main-text:contains('BART Times')

  span[class=main-text]:contains('BART Times')

  span.main-text[text="BART Times"]

  span[class=main-text][text="BART Times"]

  span.main-text[text=\"BART Times\"]

  span[class=main-text][text=\"BART Times\"]

  span[text="BART Times"]

  span[text=\"BART Times\"]

  span:contains('BART Times')

  span:contains("BART Times")

  span:contains(\"BART Times\")

So, basically I want to put a check on BOTH `class` and `TEXT` value of the span tag in CSS selector.

**Part 2:**
Then I want to get the `<section class="standard-component image-sequence-button"...` element where I found the `<span class="main-text">` and then find other elements inside that specific `section` tag

**Question 2:**
Assuming, I found the `span` tag in question 1 via CSS, how do I get the `section` tag (which is a super--- parent of the `span` tag)?

If CSS is not possible, please provide an xpath counterpart for this as a workaround for a while.

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors can't select based on text.  The answers to [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text) go into detail on why.

To select based on class and text in xpath: `//span[contains(@class, 'main-text') and text() = 'BART Times']`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 1, it is not possible, as stated in the other answer here. This is another thread about the topic : [CSS selector based on element text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text)

Regarding question 2, once again there is no such parent selector in XPath : [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector). Now for the xpath counterpart, you can use parent axis (`parent::*`) or shortcut notation for the same (`..`), or put the `span` selector as predicate for the parent (the third example below) :

```
....//span[@class = 'main-text' and text() = '%s']/parent::*
....//span[@class = 'main-text' and text() = '%s']/..
....//*[span[@class = 'main-text' and text() = '%s']]
```

See the following thread for some better (yet more complicated) alternative to match element by CSS class using XPath, just in case you haven't came across link on this topic : [How can I find an element by CSS class with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath)