# C# - webdriver: How to refer to the object

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, assert

I am doing automatic test and i want to check the occurrence of an alert with the inscription "Good morning" (when i do assert).
I am writing test in C# with selenium-webdriver.
How should I find a reference to that object?

I am using: driver.FindElement(By. ......

Element:

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-info">
<button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
Good morning
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't query the text directly using css selectors.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5441705/5111146).  What you can do is get all the elements with that class, and then iterate over them looking for the text.

```
var alerts = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.alert.alert-dismissable.alert-info"));
Assert.IsTrue(alerts.Any(element => element.Text.Contains("Good morning")));
```