# Python Selenium: Can't find element by link text

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select "seltarget" from a list of other options.

HTML:

```
<div class="filter-item" data-reactid=".3.1.0.0.1.0.0.3.0.0.0.3">seltarget</div>
```

When exported to a python file it recommends that I locate the element by xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='quickswitcher']/div/nav/ul/li/div/div/menu/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]").click()
```

This is working for the time being because "seltarget" just happens to be 5th in the list. The above line will select whichever option is 5th in the list. I want to be more specific and select the element "seltarget"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text you can select by the reactid or add a span to your seltarget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the `div` by its text, you can use the following.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='seltarget']")
```

Answer (score 5):

Locating by `link_text` works only with `<a>` tags. To locate this element you can use the class if it unique

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('filter-item').click()
```

Or the `data-reactid` attribute

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-reactid*="3.1.0.0.1.0.0.3.0.0.0.3"]').click()
```

To locate by the text you can also use `css_selector`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div:contains("seltarget")').click()
```

Or `xpath`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(), "seltarget")]').click()
```

Comment: I was able to select "seltarget" by locating it by it's `data-reactid`.
I still would like to be able to select it by it's name: "seltarget"

All of the options in the list have `class="filter-item"`

Any other recommendations?

Comment: @Chris I added options by the text