# How to put borders on non-zero table cells?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a function that outputs a table like this:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid;
}
td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  //border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
```

I need borders around non-zero elements only.
How to achieve that?
Is it possible only in CSS?

Comment: what about adding class and styling..?

Comment: That would be perfect if possible via CSS3

Comment: There is no css selector based on text, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text

Comment: There's the [`:empty`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#empty-pseudo) edge case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid;
}
td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  //border: 1px solid;
}
.asd{
border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="asd">2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="asd">1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="asd">1</td>
    <td class="asd">2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
```

try this

```
 table {
  border: 1px solid;
}
td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  //border: 1px solid;
}
.asd{
border:2px solid red;
}
```

css

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="asd">2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="asd">1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="asd">1</td>
    <td class="asd">2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution still I am open for JavaScript solutions also.