# Unable to create an appropriate CSS selector

Tags: python, css-selectors, lxml

The problem is about Python's CSS selectors.

I can't write a selector in the right way to select the item with "Last". I tried with:

```
div.pager a:[text*='Last']
```

Elements within which that item lies:

```
<div class="pager"><a href="/search/1080p/" class="current">1</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-23/">23</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-255/">Last</a> </div>
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible with just css. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text) is a post talking about it.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't possible to create a selector for certain text (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text). However you might be able to achieve what you want by doing `.pager a:last-child`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Comment: Please specify what library you're using. Python doesn't have a built-in selector library.

Comment: lxml library. I've updated my answer with the full script below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible and the answer is:

```
div.pager a:contains("Last")
```

And, here is the selector used within python script:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

main_link = "https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/"
base_link = "https://www.yify-torrent.org"

def get_links(item_link):
    response = requests.get(item_link).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    next_page = tree.cssselect('div.pager a:contains("Next")')[0].attrib["href"]
    last_page = tree.cssselect('div.pager a:contains("Last")')[0].attrib["href"]
    print(base_link + next_page," ",base_link + last_page)

get_links(main_link)
```

Results:

```
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-2/
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-255/
```

Comment: Its impossible with CSS, you can use that way with maybe jquery.

Comment: You got me wrong. I used it as css selector in python script.

Comment: Then please edit your post, give some details about it, and add a tag. Or I will edit it ^^)

Answer (score 1):

You can't select the item with `[text*='blabla']`. You can only use attributes to select them.

But anyway, if you want to select the last one, you can use `:last-of-type` or `last-child`.