# How to get elements using CSS Selector `contains` in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to use CSS Selector with `contains()` in selenium webdriver, but I'm facing `NullPointerException`.

Can someone please help?

```
private static final String testcode = "p:contains('Notes')";

public String getTextCode(String codes) throws Exception {
    String jc = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(codes)).getText();
    return jc;
}
```

Comment: `contains()` seems to be a JQuery function. Please see this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text

Comment: W3C css locator not support contains(),  selenium use native css lcoator supported by browser which describled by the W3C.  you mentioned contains() should be supported by JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [specifications](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), it is not supported. You can use XPath.