# Check if child is last - also include text nodes

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

I want to check if parents child is the last:
(so in my case, i want to select the `.icon` if it is the very last element/node in it's parent `.button`)

```
<a href="" class="button">
    <i class="icon"></i>
    Button
</a>
<a href="" class="button">
    Button
    <i class="icon"></i>
</a>
```

I tried like this: `.button .icon:last-child` also `:last-of-type`

But the selector ignores text nodes - is there a way how could i detect if the `.icon` is before / behind the text?

Comment: you mean you want to select the icon if and only if it's the last thing inside the div ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif exactly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector for text nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes)

Comment: @ovokuro i think we have a different issue that the link you put

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector based on element text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text)

Comment: @SébastienHelbert this also doesnt fit

Comment: @TemaniAfif OP wants to use CSS to detect element based on text nodes, which isn't possible, as mentioned in the answers to that question

Comment: @ovokuro not necessarly a text node ... the idea is to test if it's the very last element inside this div that may contain text

Comment: @TemaniAfif Text nodes cannot be targetted using CSS. The position doesn't matter. There may be a more appropriate duplicate, but the logic is the same

Comment: What about my answer. He wants to select the .icon only if it is last thing inside the div. Why not put the text node inside <span>

Comment: @ShashankShekhar Need to check if OP can alter HTML

Comment: Without changing the HTML markup, your only choice is JS (jquery or insert the tag). Another solution is changing the way you detect this (adding an class on parent, etc).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Place the Text node in a element

```css
.icon:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="button">
    <i class="icon">Not last child</i>
    <span>Button</span>
</a><br />
<a href="" class="button">
    <span>Button</span>
    <i class="icon">Last child</i>
</a>
```

Comment: works, but i dont want to change the html markup - thanks anyways :)

Comment: Without changing the HTML markup, your only choice is JS (jquery or insert the tag). Another solution is changing the way you detect this (adding an class on parent, etc).

Comment: When i have things like this, i avoid using elements to set the style. What i do is set an class on parent that says the icon position and use css to set the icon (if there is only one icon). This can be done setting `:before` and `:after` or floating `:before`

Comment: Won’t work if we can only control the CSS but not the HTML (e.g. in a Firefox `userContent.css`)