# How to get values of a tag if only css properties are given?

Tags: html, htmlparse

```
<td align="left" colspan="1" style="font-weight:bold">
                <span style="height:21px;padding-left:5px;color:#353535;font-size:15px">
                 Vinod Kumar
                </span>
               </td>
```

I want to access the 'Vinod kumar' from span tag. How can I do it?

Comment: This isn't possible with CSS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector based on element text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441680/css-selector-based-on-element-text)